# "Live life to the fullest" what does it mean?

Tags: idioms

I have read in some articles "live life to the fullest" and I was so confused as to what this really means. Does it mean to live happily?  I'm not so sure.

Comment: Embracing all opportunities.........................

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=define+live+life+to+the+fullest

Comment: It means whatever it means *to you*. That is the whole point. If I think I'm living my life to the fullest by *ignoring* all opportunities and instead playing with LEGO all day, then I am, in point of fact, living my life to the fullest.

Answer (score 4):

[Live life to its fullest](http://www.wikihow.com/Live-Life-to-the-Fullest) is a clichè often said to encourage people who are feeling down, a bit depressed, lonely or self-pitying. Supposedly, it is meant to inspire the listener to get off their backside, be grateful for what they do have and **LIVE!**.

The noble concept being as we have only one life, we should therefore  make the most of every opportunity and life enhancing experience that might cross our paths. Failing that, we should be "pro-active" and not wait for life to knock on our doors (another clichè) and instead actively seek these experiences.

In other words, use the time that is available wisely, to its maximum capacity, i.e., to its fullest.

Answer (score 2):

It simply means making full use of what life offers you.

Answer (score 2):

**to the fullest** is a shortened superlative formula, meaning to the fullest degree or level. There are a lot of such shortened superlative formulas, e.g. **I tried my hardest, to be at one's worst**.

Answer (score 0):

Its meaning is we should live our life happily, that we should never have any regrets, that life should not have any bounds.

Answer (score -1):

The simple meaning of this phrase is...

> Live every moment of life because you don't know what is going to happen on the very next moment.

[image]

Life is uncertain and it may end anytime without giving any notification. In this uncertainty, you should **not** lose the charm of living life every moment. To make best of your life, you should live it large.

[Here is how you live it.](http://www.wikihow.com/Live-in-the-Moment)

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion I think it means that, Live your life wisely and healthy so that you can live full life that God have given you.

Answer (score -1):

Living a fulfilled life means to be in peace with God and yourself. It means appreciating who you are, being content with what you have, planning your life to your own abilities, learning new things to add flavour to your life, engage yourself with programs that beings you happiness, and loving others.

Comment: Yes, but how do you get this from "fullest"?

Comment: This seems more like a personal philosophy than a definitive answer.

Answer (score -2):

It means to live life because it's the only one you have on Earth. Do as much as you can. It's kind of like you only have one life on Earth then the rest is heaven or hell.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Because this is a site for folks learning English, answers really should have complete words and not use chatspeak type abbreviations. It may seem a little nit-picky, but it's important to use good grammar and spelling on this SE site in particular.

Answer (score -2):

This is impossible.   If something is full it is complete, as in 100%.   Therefor it cannot be fullest, or even fuller.   The correct expression would be "living life to the full".

Comment: If it's "impossible", why do native speakers use the phrase?

Comment: Sometimes the view of the people is different from that of mathematicians.